# Is it possible to use context menu key or other keys as modifier key

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

Is it possible to use <kbd>AppsKey</kbd> (context menu key) or other keys as modifier using AutoHotKey program? (For example <kbd>AppsKey</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> opens stackoverfolow.com )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two keys together like this:

```
AppsKey & s::Run stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: SC15D
This is the scancode.
You could try this with:

```
SC15D::Soundbeep, 500,500
```

Oh , you could also use:   APPSKEY

```
APPSKEY::Soundbeep, 500,500
```